# Scalar product of two points coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

In one of the algorithms I encountered an formula to calculate a scalar number from 2 points. Given Point 1 has coordinates $(x1,y1)$ and Point 2 has coordinates $(x2, y2)$ the formula was following

$\sqrt{(y1-x1)^2 + (y2-x2)^2}$

If the $x1$ is equal to $y1$ and $x2$ is equal to $y2$ then the result is $0$. On the other hand the result grows when coordinates are far from the diagonal.

Does this formula has any name or does it serve any well known purpose e.g. in gaming?

Comment: [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)

Comment: Nope.  Check the coordinates....  Oh, and this has nothing to do with "scalar product."

Comment: @caverac But Pytagorean hypothenuse whould be $\sqrt{(x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2}$

Comment: You're right, I misread the variables. Are you sure this is the right expression?

Comment: Some context for this expression would be helpful.